# Grackn Mac Install with Homebrew - Troubleshooting - "Java is Disabled!"

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Apologies for a newbie question. I’m a student and just getting started with Grakn and CS generally.

I’m trying to install Grakn using Homebrew following the directions in the tutorial and get the following error message:

**==> Tapping graknlabs/tap
…
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/graknlabs/homebrew-tap/Formula/grakn-core.rb
grakn-core: Calling depends_on :java is disabled! Use "depends_on “openjdk@11”, "depends_on “openjdk@8” or "depends_on “openjdk” instead.

Please report this issue to the graknlabs/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/graknlabs/homebrew-tap/Formula/grakn-core.rb:9
Error: Cannot tap graknlabs/tap: invalid syntax in tap!**

Prior to attempting to install Grakn, I downloaded and installed Java 8. When I type javac - version at the command line, I get: javac 1.8.0_271

Any help getting started would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
**==> Tapping graknlabs/tap … Error: Invalid formula: 
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/graknlabs/homebrew-tap/Formula/grakn-core.rb 
grakn-core: Calling depends_on :java is disabled! Use "depends_on “openjdk@11”, 
"depends_on “openjdk@8” or "depends_on “openjdk” instead.
```

This error says there are errors on grakn-core.rb which is installed from:
https://github.com/graknlabs/homebrew-tap/blob/master/Formula/grakn-core.rb

This means you have to wait for maintener of graknlabs/homebrew-tap to fix the error. But you can create the issue to ask the maintener to fix this error, or if you know how to fix it you can create Pull request.

I just checked repositories and it seems they are fixing now(`depends_on :java => "1.8"` to `depends_on "openjdk@11"`).
You can ask when this fix will be released.
https://github.com/graknlabs/homebrew-tap/commit/00ce5619457d5014d47182094a419ac94f64fc28